# Spresense SDK + Visual Studio Code でASMPのサブコアのELFファイルがインストールされない

Tags: spresense, vscode

Visual Studio Codeを使ったIDE版開発環境にて **「ASMPワーカープログラムを追加し、ビルド、実行した際に、task生成に失敗します」** 。原因を探ろうとしているのですが、同現象の方、もしくは修正箇所ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、

お知恵をお借りしたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

▼原因
おそらく、サブコア用（ワーカー）のelfファイルがメインコアで指定している /mnt/spif/ 以下に存在しないためのように思えます。Makefile周りが原因のように考えておりますが、テンプレートから生成されるMakefileのどこかに追記や変更などが必要でしょうか？

▼実行した手順
**4.4. ASMPワーカープログラムの追加** の通りです。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_asmp%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0

▼環境
Spresense Sdk + Visual Studio Code（2019/09/24版）となります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 実行失敗時のコンソール画面]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご質問のASMPワーカープログラムのロードについて回答致します。

ご記載いただいたプログラムのログを見る限り、ご推測の通りASMPワーカーのELFファイルが存在しないことが原因です。
ELFファイルが存在しない理由としては、ELFを保存する `/mnt/spif` に空き容量が不足していることが考えられます。

以下の手順で `/mnt/spif` の空き容量を確認してください。

1. ターミナルを開く
2. `df -h` コマンドを実行する

```
NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-7.22
nsh> df -h
Filesystem    Size      Used  Available Mounted on
smartfs         4M      428K      3668K /mnt/spif
nsh>
```

もし、 `Available` が `30K` 未満(ELFファイルのサイズ+20KB程度)の場合は空き容量が不足していますので不要なファイルの削除をしてください。

以上解決の一助になれば幸いです。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: 上記内容にで、解決できました。

`/mnt/spif`を`df -h`で確認したところ容量不足であることがわかりました。

内容のファイルを削除、再度Visual Studio Codeから「Spresense:ビルドと書き込み」を実施、ASMPのワーカのバイナリが`/mnt/spif`に格納され、ASMPプログラムを実行できることが確認できました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59316/31739 にて解決できましたため、解決後のスクリーンショットを共有いたします。本質問は以上でCloseとさせていただきます。よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: dfコマンドで空き容量を確認]
[image: /mnt/spifにASMPワーカが格納されたことを確認]
[image: ASMPワーカ実行時の画面]